# Create View to display users with same select list value to each individual user

Tags: views, users

When a user registers on my site, he/she chooses the college he attended and the course he/she studied from select list fields i created using the [profile 2 module](http://www.drupal.org/project/profile2)

Is there a way to create  a View that displays to each user the people who attended the same college & studied the same course.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it creating using Views with a contextual filter.

Profile2 has integration with views, and if you create a view's page display with a path like `yoursite.com/user/[username/id]/users-with-same-college` url. You get it!

Hope it helps.

Regards.

Comment: Please can you elaborate further?

Comment: Well, you have to create a view like any other, but dont forget to select users to displat, not nodes/content. Then, you have to add a contextual filter, select any field of the profile, and the users automatically are filter by this field. Maybe this link helps you: https://www.drupal.org/node/1111722